# Время на выполнение функции - C++

Tags: c++

я делаю мультиплеерную игру, и проблема заключается в том, что люди с большим пингом тормозят ход её выполнения.
Мне нужен способ, задать на определенную функцию (в моем случае получение пакета от игрока)
Время выполнения, и если она выполняется дольше этого времени - прервать её.
Как я могу реализовать это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас три варианта:

1.
Сделать сокет асинхронным:

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

После этого, функции чтения / записи будут возвращать отрицательное число, если чтение в данный момент невозможно, а `errno` будет выставлено в `EAGAIN`

2. Перед чтением [проверять при помощи `poll/select`](https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/415259/), готовы ли данные.
   Причем эти функции позволяют задать период ожидания и следить сразу за массивом сокетов. Советую выбрать этот вариант.
3. Разово сделать операцию `recv` асинхронной - добавить  флаг `MSG_DONTWAIT` - поведение будет аналогично варианту 1.

Учебник, где все это разобрано, выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]